# How to infer component props with base component assignment

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a component library and would like to take advantage of `as` prop in it (like `react-bootstrap`). However, I am struggling with TypeScript and I have no idea how to make it infer the correct types for the selected property. I would like to make the intrinsic elements work too.

What I have is the following:

```
import React from "react";

export type AsProp<As extends React.ElementType> = {
  as?: As
} & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<As>;

type TestProps<As extends React.ElementType = 'div'> = AsProp<As> & {
  active: boolean
}

export const TestComponent: React.FC<TestProps> = props => {
  const {as: Component = 'div', ...rest} = props;

  return <Component {...rest} />;
}

export const UsageComponent = () => {
  return <TestComponent as='a' href='asd' active/>;
}
```

It seems like my code does not infer the `as` prop and i get the following error:

```
TS2322: Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"div" | undefined'.
```

How can I fix it so it infers it correctly instead of forcing me to use the default type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
export const TestComponent: React.FC<TestProps> = props => {
```

You declare `TestProps` without its generic parameter, so the default `'div'` is used. So to make this work `TestComponent` must be generic as well. An I would argue that function is where the default type belongs and NOT the the props type.

```
type TestProps<As extends React.ElementType> = AsProp<As> & {
  active: boolean
}

export function TestComponent<
  As extends React.ElementType = 'div'
>(props: TestProps<As>) {
  const {as: Component = 'div', ...rest} = props;
  return <Component {...rest} />;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljhgE8wk4BBAZwAUcwAeTnBowkAOwAmHRMRgA6AKIAbJCDEwAKsyQA+OAF44Ab3Jw4KDgH4AXOw7kAvnABk09HIDCuSKLU8IYDgB1YBgACwgAVxhkTAEObQpyJhY4dSQOGD8AuKFqEQkpZDcFZVVRDS1dA04suN0XY1M3YAA3JBsAIwgIZRRRB0oaOiwI0QxgCFFU9JhPcEm1HOExSVcMEpU1TRSDAHJxVt3tAAowXg4bNIysjjqASiMTODRJjKNzGznvNX04fcOADRwWQgogZRwGM7+DgUUxEGARKBTPhfBblIwg2RgmCOAD0CQG5BeojeIgyACFfnwrrMvGj4GhFOYOAA5FCqPT4czifBmcZtOD4omveBkmBsKk01E+dHmPS7FC7OChIiYeXcpXNNpCoA)

Comment: What about forwardRef? [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljhgE8wk4BBAZwAUcwAeTnBowkAOwAmHRMRgA6AKIAbJCDEwAKsyQA+OAF44Ab3Jw4KDgH4AXOw7kAvnABk09HIDCuSKLU8IYDgB1YBgACwgAVxhkTAEObQpyJhY4dSQOGD8AuKFqEQkpZDcFZVVRDS1dA04suN0XY1M3YAA3JBsAIwgIZRRRB0oaOng0CFEM1PSYT3AxtX1XDFlMaAB3FChxGIAKTAjRDGAxuBzhMUlFuSUVNU0UgwBycVaH7W2wXg4bNIysjjqADRwIiYGxFJYAMTWG3ESC2SFinG0AEojCY4KNxvBDOYbDNvPNHs8Wg8gbJyUQMo4DB9-BxEqYiDAIlBRCd8XNykZybJKTBHCC9IYQfYAPQJBzIxLkTETEQZABCCz4P2mXk5I0U5g4ADkUKo9PhzOJ8GZDm04OKZWM5VM2MrVRyfFzzHoHigHnBQoL3RxxJ7mharUA)